# How do I access CurseForge's API?

Tags: c#, api

I've been trying to access CurseForge's API for a while now. I have read their documentation at least 7 times at this point and can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("X-Api-Token", "<hidden>");
wc.DownloadFile("https://minecraft.curseforge.com/api/game/dependencies", @".\cache\info.json");
```

Whenever I do this, I get a 404 error and I don't understand why, as the URL above is literally an example of what to do in the documentation.

Comment: I looked it up and it lead me to a reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/7tsbic)(2017) with the same issue(and API URL). I found this in that thread: https://twitchappapi.docs.apiary.io/, I hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: Okay I see, that makes sense. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem can't be solved, so just use https://twitchappapi.docs.apiary.io/ instead! It has most of the same features but actually works.